# How do I make a button that sends a push message to one specific user using web Firebase?

Tags: html, firebase, button, push-notification

I've been hosting a website using Firebase, and I don't know how to send a push notification once someone presses a button on my website. I've already managed to host , get my key while accessing it, and send a notification to myself using the Firebase console website. Is there a way for me to send the same notification I would send using Firebase's console, but with a press of a button on my web? Should I not be using Firebase at all if I want to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are child_changed, child_added events for real time database fields, you can add one of them and listen the notification from your website.

Please check [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) retrieve data page.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Child_changed and child_added aren't supposed to return to me messages I've already sent, and not send a message? Or did I not understand what the data page meant?

Comment: when you subscribe one of this event in website, if the field change, event fired and you can catch it in website. Think like two user session in website, one changes something and other will be notified ( if you listen this field with these events).

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented a function that sends a message using : `firebase.database().ref(..).push( notification:{...}, message: ... and sender: ...)`.But it all just appears as a message on the console. How do I make it an actual notification, like the ones that generate a pop-up if the user is not on the tab?